# Separate Controller for each View or a single controller for one concern in MVC-Pattern?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, model-view-controller

I'm building a Windows Forms C#-Application and try to use the MVC pattern.

Right now, I have a controller that controls one of my model classes.

It has functions to add, update, delete and list the content of the model (which is just a class that inherits from `Collection<T>`) or show the `AddForm` (see below).

Probably I will need to add a few functions but these are the basics.

I also have 2 views:

- A Windows forms (`ListForm`) with a `ListView` control, an add, edit and a delete button
- And another Windows form (`AddForm`) with some textboxes and ok/cancel buttons.

If I click the add or edit button, the `AddForm` should open.

So the `AddForm` needs the edit and add functions from the controller, while the `ListForm` needs the list and delete functions.

Should I create a separate controller for the `AddForm` that only contains the add/edit and validation functions (while the `ListForm` one only contains show/delete)?

Should I simply inject both views into my controller?

Or should I just show the form and call all the add/edit-stuff within the `showAddForm()` method of 
the controller?

Comment: You are trying to change an MVP pattern into and MVC pattern (so working against the grain here): http://joel.inpointform.net/software-development/mvvm-vs-mvp-vs-mvc-the-differences-explained/ Aside from that, I would want to consolidate related concerns under the same controller.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that this was MVP.
Well, then it's MVP I guess.

Answer (score 1):

The controller should contain the backend code for multiple views.  I group the controller at the entity level for CRUD operations.  For example, in an HR application, I would have an employee controller, a department controller, etc.  I would not split it out by operation.